# What are the usecases and usefulness when passing pointer to data member to std::invoke?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, stdthread, c++-concepts

I was reading about [std::invoke](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) on cpp reference and was wondering in which situations we would ever need to pass as a first argument a pointer to data member and an object as second argument.

From cpp reference it states this:

> Invoke the Callable object f with the parameters args. As by INVOKE(std::forward(f), std::forward(args)...).
>
> where INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN) is defined as follows:

...

and then the second point is:

> Otherwise, if N == 1 and f is a pointer to data member of class

Ok, let's look at this further and suppose I'm using `std::thread` (which constructor's uses `std::invoke`):

For example, it is a bit unclear to me when it would be useful (or what can force one) to use a threads this way ?

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int num) : num_(num) {}
    void print_add(int i) const { std::cout << num_+i << '\n'; }
    int num_;

    void print_num(int i) const {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    const Foo foo(314159);
    std::thread t(&Foo::num_, foo);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

And how a pointer to data member can be associated with a callable concept ?

Comment: Data members can have an overloaded `operator()`.  Just think about if your class was holding a `std::function` member you want to call.

Comment: @NathanOliver ok, but why not pass that member functor directly to a thread instead of the data member itself ?

Comment: What if all you have is a container of data member pointers?  Or you have several different function members and then set a pointer to the one the class is actually using?

Comment: @NathanOliver Can you bring a code example of that ?

Comment: I don't have anything handy.  I would have to write a contrived example to showcase either of the two use cases I mentioned which you should be able to do yourself.

Comment: You talk about `std::invoke` but the question then only revolves around the example of `std::thread`. Surely there are valid use cases for this without involving `std::thread`.

Comment: @super what are those valid usecases ?

Comment: If used to write generic code, you could pass in both a getter function or a direct member and both would work. You could also pass in references or pointers to the object and both would work. Additionally you could pass in `std::reference_wrappers` and the generic code could stay the same and work for all those cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might think that only pointers to member functions are useful. That is, something like:

```
struct Widget {
    bool valid() const;
};

std::vector<Widget> widgets;
bool all_valid = std::ranges::all_of(widgets, &Widget::valid);
```

That would `std::invoke` the pointer to member function `&Widget::valid` on each of the `Widget`s. But you could just as easily have constructed `Widget` such that `valid` is just a flag instead of being a member function. And checking that all the `Widget`s are `valid` is just as reasonable a thing to do:

```
struct Widget {
    bool valid;
};

std::vector<Widget> widgets;
bool all_valid = std::ranges::all_of(widgets, &Widget::valid);
```

The only difference is that this `std::invoke`s a pointer to member *data* instead of a pointer to member *function*. But still useful.

Comment: I just don't thank that such typical member functions like `valid()` won't return bool data member.

Comment: And having only data member can be encapsulation violation.